# Is GripRite Shingle Underlayment -LWE an OK replacement for Tyvek HomeWrap under vinyl siding?

Tags: underlayment, vinyl-siding

I have a contractor replacing old aluminum siding with vinyl siding. The contract stated Tyvek would be used, but I just noticed today (unfortunately 2.5/4 outer walls are already 'finished') that they are using Griprite shingle Underlayment LWE, instead of Tyvek Homewrap.
We live in Northern Maryland, USA and get 4 seasons of various weather conditions. Is this a problem I absolutely need to bring up and get fixed or will this be OK long-term?

Comment: It seems similar enough.  You might look into the cost difference and if the contractor is passing on savings if any.

Comment: You wouldn't have any issue if they were putting it on the roof under your shingles, so I can't see any issue with having it on the walls. Unusual? Yes, but he may have had a supply left over from a previous job or got a good deal buying in bulk and is using it instead of a more "conventional" housewrap...